# What is the style of UIView subclass used in this popover in Safari on iPad?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

For the iPad app I am writing I want a style of popover that is identical to the one used in Safari when you tap on the "+" UITabbarItem to add a bookmark or add the current Web page to the Home screen. Here is a screenshot of the popover I am refering to:

[alt text http://www.daturner.com/stackoverflow/popover.png](http://www.daturner.com/stackoverflow/popover.png)

Can someone please identify the UIView subclass or subclasses that make up the contents of the popover?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `UIActionSheet`. If you've got a `UIBarButtonItem` that's calling an action method, you can initialize the sheet as you usually would and then call `-showFromBarButtonItem:animated:` on it, passing in the bar button item as the first parameter.